# How to implement a exercise in The Go Programming Language

Tags: go, bytestream

Exercise 7.5:
The `LimitReader` function in the `io` package accepts an `io.Reader` `r` and a number of bytes `n`, and returns another `Reader` that reads from `r` but reports an end-of-file condition after `n` bytes. Implement it.

```
func LimitReader(r io.Reader, n int64) io.Reader
```

How to implement it?

---

Below is my code, I know it not right.

```
type MyReader struct {
    bytes []byte
    length int
}

func (myReader *MyReader) Read (p []byte) (int, error) {
    fmt.Println("be invoked")
    myReader.bytes = p
    myReader.length = len(p)
    fmt.Printf("lenght: %d\n" , myReader.length)
    return len(p), nil
}
func LimitReader(r io.Reader, n int64) io.Reader {
    filecontent, _:= ioutil.ReadFile("./testfile.txt")
    r.Read(filecontent[:n])
    return r
}

func main() {
    myReader := &MyReader{}
    r := LimitReader(myReader, 100)
    filecontent, _:= ioutil.ReadFile("./testfile.txt")
    fmt.Println(r.Read(filecontent))
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question we could help you with?

Comment: Maybe check out the documentation of [io.Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader)

Comment: I think it'll be better to write your own code (though incomplete or not working) and request a review to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I just want konw how to implement this exercise  @jcbwlkr

Comment: I update my code. @philipjkim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are not clear with the concepts of what you need to do.

You need to create a function with the following signature:

```
func LimitReader(r io.Reader, n int64) io.Reader
```

That is, an `r` `io.Reader` and an `n` number is passed to it, and you have to return a new `io.Reader`. When someone reads from the *returned* reader, the read data must come from the passed `r` reader, and it should automatically count the read bytes; and if the read bytes exceeds the `n` number, it *must not* read further bytes from `r` but return `io.EOF` which is used to indicate that the end of the stream is reached. It could be that the `r` reader has more bytes (meaning more bytes could be read from it), but that should not be read and returned: that's the purpose of the `LimitedReader`.

If you think you understand the problem now, stop reading the answer for now, and try to implement this yourself. What follows is an example solution.

---

This exact functionality already exists in the [`io`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/) package, and goes by the same name: [`io.LimitReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitReader).

```
// LimitReader returns a Reader that reads from r
// but stops with EOF after n bytes.
// The underlying implementation is a *LimitedReader.
func LimitReader(r Reader, n int64) Reader { return &LimitedReader{r, n} }
```

It returns a value of [`*io.LimitedReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitedReader), whose implementation is this:

```
// A LimitedReader reads from R but limits the amount of
// data returned to just N bytes. Each call to Read
// updates N to reflect the new amount remaining.
type LimitedReader struct {
    R Reader // underlying reader
    N int64  // max bytes remaining
}

func (l *LimitedReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if l.N <= 0 {
        return 0, EOF
    }
    if int64(len(p)) > l.N {
        p = p[0:l.N]
    }
    n, err = l.R.Read(p)
    l.N -= int64(n)
    return
}
```

Take a minute or 2 to try to understand the code yourself. If you're stuck or not everything is clear, read on.

**Explaining the code:**

`io.LimitedReader` is a struct, which contains the *source* reader it reads from, and the number of bytes that can still be read without having to report `io.EOF`. So `LimitReader()` simply just returns a value of this struct where the parameters `r` and `n` are assigned to the fields `R` and `N` of the struct. More specifically an address of this struct is returned, because `LimitedReader.Read()` has pointer receiver, and so only a pointer to it implements `io.Reader`. And it has a pointer receiver, because the `Read()` method (may) modify the fields of the struct, so a pointer is required to be able to do that (else only a copy would be modified which is discarded after the `Read()` method returns).

`LimitedReader.Read()` first checks the `N` field which tells how many more bytes can we return, and if there is no more "allowed", being a well-behaved Limited-reader, it returns `io.EOF` immedately without reading any more bytes from the source:

```
if l.N <= 0 {
    return 0, EOF
}
```

If `N` is positive, that means *some* bytes may be read and returned, but no more than `N`, so if the `p` slice passed to `Read()` has a greater length, we *re-slice* it so a call to the source reader will not read more than what we should allow:

```
if int64(len(p)) > l.N {
    p = p[0:l.N]
}
```

And the last part is nothing more that actually doing the reading, from the source reader:

```
n, err = l.R.Read(p)
```

Which returns the number of actually read bytes, and an optional error (whether reading encountered some error). Since we're about to return these, we have to administer that this amount of bytes are now returned, we have to subtract this from the allowed remaining bytes:

```
l.N -= int64(n)
return
```